# Access methods based on constructor provided

Tags: java, constructor

In my program, I want to be able to access certain methods based on the constructor I initialize and nothing else. For example:

```
public class A {
    int paramOne;
    float paramTwo;

    public A(int paramOne) {
        // Constructor One
    }

    public A(float paramTwo) {
        // Constructor Two
    }

    public void ConstructorOneMethodOnly(int paramOne) {
        // Only used when Constructor One is initialized
    }

    public void ConstructorTwoMethodOnly(float paramTwo) {
        // Only used when Constructor Two is initialized
    }

}
```

In the code given, is there a way of achieving what I have described in the comments and in my question? If so, can you describe how to do so?

Comment: No, you can't restrict the accessibility of a method based on the constructor used to create an object.

Comment: Ahh bummer, that's no good. :/

Comment: I agree with what @Sotirios said. But having said that, you can call the corresponding methods in their respective constructors. That's the only way I see for this sort of problem.

Comment: 2 classes is probably the way to go, or generics if the difference is only int/float

Comment: Why is this question -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Sotirios Delimanolis' comment, you can not restrict the accessibility of a method based on the constructor used.

I think this logic should be divided into two class, that is the more clear implementation I can find out.

```
public class IntDemo {

    int paramOne;

    public IntDemo (int paramOne) {
        ...
    }

    public void ConstructorOneMethodOnly(int paramOne) {
        ...
    }

}

class FloatDemo {

    float paramTwo;

    public FloatDemo(float paramTwo) {
        ...
    }

    public void ConstructorTwoMethodOnly(float paramTwo) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just thought about it then and I probably could implement an interface or extend an abstract class for the rest of the functionality. Thanks.

Comment: I can not see the implementation of your methods in your question, that is why hesitated to suggest abstract class...!!!

Comment: Yeah was just a quick example not the entire code. Should of been more clear on that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    int paramOne;
    float paramTwo;
    int constr = 0;

    public A(int paramOne) {
        // Constructor One
        constr = 1; 
    }

    public A(float paramTwo) {
        // Constructor Two
        constr = 2;
    }
}
```

and check `constr` variable before invoking methods.

Comment: Yeah have been doing it this way but I guess there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this directly helps you but it may help you and more.

I suggest using a generic class like this.

```
public class A<T> {

    public A(final T t) {

    }

    public void method(final T t) {

    }
}
```

If you dont know how to use a generic class here is an exmaple

```
final A<Integer> aInteger = new A<Integer>(1);
final A<Float> aFloat = new A<Float>(5.4f);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but would like to not use generics for this. It is a good suggestion however.